# Traversing a firebase database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ios10

Swift 3.x iOS 10.

Trying to understand Databases in firebase. Imported some JSON data into my app and managed to read it back. This the code.

```
let rootRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "0")
print("\(rootRef.key)")   
let nextRef = rootRef.child("identity")
print("\(nextRef)")

nextRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
    print("\(snapshot.value)")
})
```

Which works, my data looks like this ...

[image: Firebase database]

But how to do this if I want to traverse the database, looking at record 2, record 3 etc etc where I am not sure how many records I actually got.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found it, well something that works...

```
let rootRef = Database.database().reference()
rootRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
    print("dump \(snapshot.children.allObjects)")
})
```

I post for posterity :)

Comment: Nice answer ;). Using `observeSingleEvent` might be a better fit here (i.e., if you only intend to read the *current* data and not every update). Also keep in mind that this solution might not scale well if your Firebase database becomes huge...